# Is $C_\mathrm{c}^\infty (\mathbb R^d \setminus \lbrace 0 \rbrace ) \subset H^{m,p}(\mathbb R^d )$ dense?

Tags: real-analysis, sobolev-spaces

The title says it:

$$C_\mathrm{c}^\infty (\mathbb R^d ) \subset H^{m,p}(\mathbb R^d )$$ is a dense subset. Is the same true if I leave out one point, i.e., is
$$C_\mathrm{c}^\infty (\mathbb R^d \setminus \lbrace 0 \rbrace ) \subset H^{m,p}(\mathbb R^d )$$
dense? I expect this to depend upon $m,p,d$...

Comment: Easy remark dealing with the case $m=1$: If $p>n$ then this is false (since $H^{1,p}\subset C^{0,1-n/p}$). In case $p<n$ I suspect that this is true and I would not guess about $p=n$.